# How to customize classes fo sublevel menu items

Tags: submenu

I've been looking around for a while and couldnt find a solution to my problem.

I need to add classes to submenu li items.

I've tryed to figure out editing `Topmenu.php` and `Navigation.php` (both inside `core/Mage/Catalog` and `Core/Mage/` )

It looks kind of like this now

```
<ul>
<li class="first nav-1">link</li>
<li class="nav-2">link
  <ul>
    <li class="level1">sublink</li>
     <li class="level1">sublink</li>
    <li class="level1">sublink</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="last nav-3">link</li>
</ul>
```

And thats what I need it to look like:

```
<ul>
<li class="first nav-1">link</li>
<li class="nav-2">link
  <ul>
    <li class="level1 nav1">sublink</li>
     <li class="level1 nav2">sublink</li>
    <li class="level1 nav3">sublink</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="last nav-3">link</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The category tree should be built here: `\Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu::_getHtml`

But I recommend, to overthink your concept. Everything you want, is achievable with the [n-thchild() selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).